# Reverse an infix expression in C?

Tags: c

Such that a string of "23+45" becomes "45+23"?
This is in relation to converting an infix expression to prefix expression, with the goal here being to be able to first reverse the infix expression

Comment: * why do you need to reverse the infix expression? * what you are asking for is not reversing a string: reversing your string would be `"54+32"`, you are asking to swap the operands * you must operate on tokens, not on character strings * this means you need to parse the string first * you need to show your attempt and ask a specific question about a specific issue you encountered in your approach

Comment: And is this meant to do something with 23 + 45  + 96 + 11? [what?]

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do so is to code some [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) building some [concrete syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) in memory.

So you would first define *several* `struct`-s representing the various nodes of that tree (as a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) type), then code the parser, then code the transformation of nodes, then code their printer. Read wikipage on [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

You may want to use parser generators like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/).

You certainly should read books like the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) before coding.

You should also read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

You could **take inspiration from the source code of *existing* open source programs** like [GNUmeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/) or [octave](https://octave.org/) or [GNUplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or [Lua](https://lua.org/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

PS. For a university homework, mention the source code you did study. Your teacher might be delighted you read them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a readable and easy to understand solution. It's not the most efficient, but if you are doing infix/postfix notations you are not concern with performance:

```
/* \brief swap in-place the operands of an expression of form `lhs op rhs` (no spaces)
 * where op is a single character operator
 *
 * \param expr string representing the expression. Must follow specified form
 * \param operator single character operator
 *
 * \post \p expr will contain `rhs op lhs` (no spaces)
 */
void reverse_expr(char* expr, char operator)
{
    char* buffer = malloc(strlen(expr) + 1);

    char* const operator_pos = strchr(expr, operator);
    if (operator_pos == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid expression: missing '%c'", operator);
        free(buffer);
        exit(1);
    }

    *operator_pos = '\0';
    sprintf(buffer, "%s+%s", expr, operator_pos + 1);
    strcpy(expr, buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```